# Using Stripe Checkout to Allow a Customer to Purchase a Product

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I've yet to find an answer to what should be a very straightforward approach to using Stripe (in my opinion). Using Stripe Checkout, how can I allow a person to pay for a product that I already have created in my "Products" section of the dashboard? All documentation that I have found shows how to retrieve product data, etc., and that's great, but it doesn't actually explain how to allow the customer to *purchase* the product with Checkout. I'm using PHP, but would be more than happy to see any examples in any language to follow the trajectory.

Comment: You just want to charge them the value of your product? Products just really describe plans, and have no individual pricing. If you are not creating subscriptions then you need to go another route.

Comment: No, that's the easy part. I want them to actually buy the product that has a monthly subscription cost associated with it. Stripe assigns a product ID, and I'm just trying to figure out how someone can even purchase it if the API doesn't allow for a "data-product" attribute, for example. It only asks for a dollar amount.

Comment: You want to subscribe a customer to a particular plan?

Comment: Yes. I have 3 plans listed under 1 product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attempting to do this using `checkout.js` or `stripe elements`, it is not possible. You will need to handle this server side by:

First get a token that's a representation of the card the customer submitted using [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js)
         
         
              
              
              
                  
              
              
              
              subscribe

Script:

```
    $('.btn-save-sub').click(function () {
         //if your customer has chosen a plan, for example 
          var plan = $("#plan_id").val();
          var stripe = Stripe(//your public key here );
          var elements = stripe.elements();

          /**create and mount cc and cc exp elements**/
          var card = elements.create('card'); //complete card element, can be customized
          card.mount('#card-element');

          card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
               var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
               if (event.error) {
                   displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
               }else{
                   displayError.textContent = '';
               }
            });

           var form = document.getElementById('subscription_add_new_source');

           stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                }else{
                    //post result.token.id  and plan_id to your server, this token represents the card you will be using 
                }
        });
    });
```

Now, server side you have a token and a plan_id (if you've decided to allow customer to select a plan). Now we will subscribe the customer to the plan using stripe's [PHP Bindings](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php)

```
 //you have posted a plan_id to be used, you will create a subscription for that plan id, create a card objecting using the token you have, and attach that card as a default source to the stripe customer

 $stripe_customer= //retrieve it, if you don't have one, create it
```

[Create customer via stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer)

Once you have your customer you will first create a card object and assign that as the default source:

```
//create new card
$new_card = $stripe_customer->sources->create(array('sources'=>$posted_token));

//assign newly created card as customer's default source
//subscriptions can only charge default sources 
$stripe_customer->default_source = $new_card->id; 

//finally, create a subscription with the plan_id 
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(
        array(
            'customer' => $stripe_customer->id,
            'items' => array(
                array(
                    'plan' => $posted_plan_id,       
                )
            ),
            'trial_end' =>$end // represents the first day a  customer will be charged for this plan, pass a timestamp 
        )
    );
```

Comment: There is a [`data-panel-label`](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#optional) option that you can use to show text like "Subscribe" instead of "Pay $x" if using Checkout. But yep, you're right, you have to create the customer and subscribe them to the plan on the server side using the token you get from Checkout/Element, good answer.